# Build.Gradle file broken after install of Flutter and Dart

Tags: android, flutter

I had several Android Studio android projects, which all worked just fine. Last night I installed the Flutter and Dart plugins. Now every project I had previously is broken. It will not build. I opened the project's build.gradle file and this is what it now looks like, which is nothing at all like how it's supposed to be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/lib" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.dart_tool" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.idea" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.pub" />
```

Can I simply delete this and recreate it? Or is there a way to have AS regenerate this file? I do not know how it ended up this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by replacing that xml content with the example gradle file from the Android Studio documentation.

```
/**
 * The buildscript block is where you configure the repositories and
 * dependencies for Gradle itself—meaning, you should not include dependencies
 * for your modules here. For example, this block includes the Android plugin for
 * Gradle as a dependency because it provides the additional instructions Gradle
 * needs to build Android app modules.
 */

buildscript {

    /**
     * The repositories block configures the repositories Gradle uses to
     * search or download the dependencies. Gradle pre-configures support for remote
     * repositories such as JCenter, Maven Central, and Ivy. You can also use local
     * repositories or define your own remote repositories. The code below defines
     * JCenter as the repository Gradle should use to look for its dependencies.
     *
     * New projects created using Android Studio 3.0 and higher also include
     * Google's Maven repository.
     */

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    /**
     * The dependencies block configures the dependencies Gradle needs to use
     * to build your project. The following line adds Android plugin for Gradle
     * version 4.0.0 as a classpath dependency.
     */

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}

/**
 * The allprojects block is where you configure the repositories and
 * dependencies used by all modules in your project, such as third-party plugins
 * or libraries. However, you should configure module-specific dependencies in
 * each module-level build.gradle file. For new projects, Android Studio
 * includes JCenter and Google's Maven repository by default, but it does not
 * configure any dependencies (unless you select a template that requires some).
 */

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
}
```

After that, I rebuilt the file and then Android asked me to update Gradle. Once I did that, the app worked fine again.